# Increment rank for each break in consecutive sequence (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data relating to a loyalty program in a retail outlet store. When a customer hasn't purchased from the store within 60 days, they are considered lapsed, and a promotion is sent out to get them to purchase again.

I am trying to do some analysis on how many consecutive times they come back, and how many promotions we have to give them.

A 'spree' is defined as a customer purchasing products without a 60-day break. e.g. if a customer buys a product every 59 days for their lifetime, they will only have a spree of 1.

I am trying to find a simple piece of workaround code to get the output presented below. All the input data is already in a table.

Input data looks like this

[image: Input]

Output should look like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: DOnt give screenshots give sample data it can be useful

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Did you try anything? Do you have a question?

Comment: how to code it properly. I can't rank or dense rank the Y's, as it just completely disregards the N's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking query as below:

```
;With Cte as (
    Select *, Spree = sum(Case when Lapsed = 'Y' and NextLapsed = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Customerid order by PurchaseDate)
     from (
        Select *, NextLapsed = lead(lapsed) over(partition by customerid order by purchasedate) 
        from #YourCustomer
    ) a
) 
Select *, [Consecutive Purchases] = Row_Number() over (partition by customerid, spree order by purchaseDate )
from Cte
```

Some assumptions

1. PurchaseDate is ascending and I used based on that order
2. Spree and Consecutive purchases based on each customer